How can I demonstrate the existence of such an isomorphism(look at the image below)?
While I was reading a paper from "Daniel Shumow" about recovering all possible plaintexts when bad RSA keys ($e$ and $\phi(N)$ aren't co-prime) generation occurs, I found this isomorphism (see the picture below). So, I'm wondering about a way to demonstrate its existence.


The section in the paper mentions an additional condition on $e$.

For the sake of straight forward presentation, the analysis will proceed with the further assumption that $(p − 1)(q − 1)$ is not divisible by any higher powers of $e$.

This means that $\phi(N)=e \times f$, where $gcd⁡(e,f)=1$. We will now use the structure theorem for finite Abelian groups.

If $H$ is a finite Abelian group, then
$$H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{k_1}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_2^{k_2}} \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_m^{k_m}}$$
where $p_i$'s need not be distinct primes.

In our setting, $H = (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*$, so $|H| = \phi(N) = e \times f$. Since, $gcd(e,f)=1$, we have
$$(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^* \cong \mathbb{Z}_{e} \times G'$$
where $|G'| = f$. Let $\phi : (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^* \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{e} \times G' $ be an isomorphic mapping. We now have the following observations.

There is a unique subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*$ that has order $e$. This is because there is only one subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{e} \times G'$ that has order $e$ which is $\mathbb{Z}_{e} \times 1$. Using Cauchy's theorem for finite group, there exists an element $g$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*$ of order $e$. Let $E$ be the cyclic group generated by $g$, i.e., $E = \langle g \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_e$ and $|E| = e$. Remember, for any $x \in E$, we have $\phi(x) = (y, 1)$.
Let $G$ be the subset of $(\mathbb{Z} / N\mathbb{Z})^*$ in which the order of the elements is not divisible by $e$. Then, $G$ is a subgroup. This is because the order of the elements in $G'$ is also not divisible by $e$. In this case, for any $x \in G$, we have $\phi(x) = (1, y)$.

Therefore, we get
$$(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^* \cong E \times G$$

but the G' isn't isomorph to Z/bZ with b is power of a prime

what i mean , is that how we know that G' is cyclic

@g2f1 $G'$ need not be cyclic. We only know that it is of the form $\underset{i}{\times} \mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{k_i}}$. Why do we require $G'$ to be cyclic?

but Z/bZ is cyclic with b is a power of a prime

i think there is another result we can use check this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410104/let-g-be-an-abelian-with-vert-g-vert-mn-and-gcdm-n-1-prove-that-g-i ,and tell me if i'm right

@g2f1 Let's continue the discussion in the following chat - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/154645/how-can-i-demonstrate-the-existence-of-such-an-isomorphismlook-at-the-image-belo?tab=general

@g2f1 Yes, the math stackexchange post gives an alternate proof.

If $e$ is prime and divides $\varphi(N)$ exactly, in the sense that $e$ is coprime to $\varphi(N)/e$, then the result is true and follows from, e.g., the structure theorem for finite abelian groups.
Without that assumption, the result is technically not correct: for example, if say $e^2$ divides $p-1$, no isomorphism of the form (1) exists.
